# TIMESTAMP on HIVE table

Tags: hive, cloudera, sqoop, impala, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm trying to load data from Oracle to Hive as parquet. Every time i load a table with date/timestamp column to hive, it automatically converts these columns to BIGINT. Is is possible to load timestamp/date formats to hive using sqoop and as a parquet file?

Already tried creating the table first in hive then using impala to LOAD DATA INPATH the parquet file.
Still failed with errors

> "file XX has an incompatible Parquet schema for column XX column:
>   TIMESTAMP"

BTW, I'm using cloudera quickstart vm. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Cloudera documentation:](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_parquet.html)

If you use Sqoop to convert RDBMS data to Parquet, be careful with interpreting any resulting values from DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP columns. The underlying values are represented as the Parquet INT64 type, which is represented as BIGINT in the Impala table. The Parquet values represent the time in milliseconds, while Impala interprets BIGINT as the time in seconds. Therefore, if you have a BIGINT column in a Parquet table that was imported this way from Sqoop, divide the values by 1000 when interpreting as the TIMESTAMP type.

Or you can also use your Hive query like this to get the result in your desired TIMESTAMP format.

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(CAST(SUBSTR(timestamp_column, 1,10) AS INT)) AS timestamp_column;
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like there's no way i can import date/timestamp formats to hive from parquet.

Comment: This problem is with parquet file right now. You can use ORC format to import in timestamp with option `--map-column-hive <cols_name>=TIMESTAMP`. ORC file format has better performance then parquet.

Comment: @SandeepSingh does sqoop import support import in ORC  format directly ? i think we have to first import in text and then create the hive table to store in ORC format ?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Not directly but using `--hcatalog-table` option you can import directly into existing ORC Hive table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using configuration of sqoop

```
--map-column-hive
<cols_name>=TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Already tried that but it seems that sqoop ignores that configuration once we use --as-parquetfile option

Comment: I can't find any option as "--as-parquetfile"
Only 3 type: 
`--as-avrodatafile Imports data to Avro Data Files
--as-sequencefile Imports data to SequenceFiles
--as-textfile Imports data as plain text (default)`

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html

Comment: try this one: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_microsoft_sql_connector